Getting previous type 1 transaction date before each transaction
Python df got columns as
Customerid, date, sale type, amount.
Customerid s
11,11,11,12,12
Date s
May/6/2022,may/8/2022,jan/10/2023, feb/1/2023,feb/2/2023
Sale types
Type2, type1, type1,type2,type1
Amont s
10,12,14,16,17
I need to get the previous date of sale where type=type2 with respect to each row means wrt each customer, each transaction.
My df is very big. 2.6 million of rows.
I m wotking on pithon notebook
I am expecting a table like this
